# Deployment of Django app to AWS Lambda using zappa fails even though Zappa says your app is live at the following link

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-s3, lambda, zappa

I came across the amazing serverless AWS Lambda recently and thought it would be great to have my app up there and not have to worry about auto scaling, load balancing and all for apparently a fraction of the cost.

So then I found out about Zappa which takes care of deploying your python app to AWS Lambda for you. Amazing is what I thought.

Its actually on paper very easy to do. just follow the instructions here..
https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa

Anyway I followed the instructions with just a very basic django app using virtualenv that just contained the django rest framework tutorial in it..
Tested it locally and works fine.

Then I set up my s3 bucket and authenticated my credentials with the awscli.

Then I ran the 2 thing you need to deply. 
Zappa init,
Zappa deploy dev.

Then it went through all its processes, packaging into zip, deploying etc...

Then at the end it said your app is live and here is the url
It gave me a url to try.
I pasted the url into the browser and this is what the browser displayed for me.
Oh yeah and my s3 bucket is still empty and so is my aws lambda service.

```
{
    "message": "An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request.", 
    "traceback": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):\n", 
        "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 395, in handler\n    response = Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ)\n", 
        "  File \"/home/donagh/projects/vizzydev/vizzy/visualid/vizzy_django/env/build/Werkzeug/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 865, in from_app\n", 
        "  File \"/home/donagh/projects/vizzydev/vizzy/visualid/vizzy_django/env/build/Werkzeug/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app\n", 
        "  File \"/home/donagh/projects/vizzydev/vizzy/visualid/vizzy_django/env/build/Werkzeug/werkzeug/test.py\", line 871, in run_wsgi_app\n", 
        "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\n"
    ]
}
```

If anyone as any ideas I would be very grateful. I would love to get this working. It would be an incredibly powerful resource.

Comment: Did 'zappa tail' give you anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

When I get errors related to `werkzeug wrapper` it is usually because my packages were not installed in my virtual environment.

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install Django
pip install zappa
# pip install any other packages
# or with a requirements.txt file
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then run the `zappa` deploy commands.